# full text search excluding a specific criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table called items and I enabled full text searching on name column

```
  id         name             price
 ----       ------           -------
  1          brown wood       550
  2          black wood       430
  3          wooden chair     15
  4          kitchen knife    3
  5          sponge ball      1.35
```

I want to write a query to select all items whom name doesn't include 'wood' using full text search

so the result would be

```
  id         name             price
 ----       ------           -------
  4          kitchen knife    3
  5          sponge ball      1.35
```

here is my query

```
 SELECT * FROM items WHERE Match(name) Against('-wood' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Comment: I removed the Oracle tag because it does not have `match()`.

Comment: oh okay I wasn't knowing that thanks

Comment: Use -wood insted of -kids.

Comment: sorry it was by by fault but also doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want `wood`, then the fist stab at a query would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM items
WHERE Match(name) Against('-wood*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

However, the `-` only works *after* other terms are matched.  So, you need some sort of positive match.  Something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM items
WHERE Match(name) Against('k* and -wood*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

If you know that such exclusions are common, you might include a particular word in every name (say, "name").  Alternatively, you might need to resort to `like`:

```
select *
from items i
where concat(' ', name' not like '% wood%';
```

Comment: no one works and I want to accomplish this using match and against not like